# Unusual results from running chi square test with stats.chi2_contingency()

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm running a chi square test on some categorical values pertaining to race, and whether different racial groups participated in a clinic. As there's about a dozen different races in this data, I bucketed them down to 'White', 'Black' and 'Other', just for the purposes of testing (as the correlations indicated most of the activity occurring between 'White and 'Black'. However, using Python's .chi2_contingency() method, I'm getting results back that seem unusual. The table is below:

```
    Appointment Status    No    Yes

Black                    9170   33372
White                    15137  152307
Other                    8864   56165
```

The Python method returns the following:

```
X^2: 5207.16
p-value: 0.0
df: 2
expected values array:  array([[  5131.21350472,  37410.78649528],
                               [  7843.48838791,  57185.51161209],
                               [ 20196.29810738, 147247.70189262]]))
```

The df is good, but the chi square value and p-value both don't seem right. Is there something anyone can see that I might be doing methodologically that might be producing these values, or might there be something going on behind the scenes in Python that's doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Add part of your code so people can reproduce your results.

Answer (score 1):

The test statistic and p-value are correct (and perhaps also understandable). Let me stepwise explain the outcome. The section entitled ``Example chi-squared test for categorical data'' on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test#Example_chi-squared_test_for_categorical_data) might help as well.

- The expected count is the number of observations that would end up in a given cell of the table if we would assume independence. The fractions of Black and No are 0.15468974 and 0.12061524, respectively. Under independence, we expect 0.15468974x0.12061524x275015=5131.21350472 observations in the sample to be labeled as Black and No (Note: 275015 is the total number of observations).
- All other expected counts are calculated similar. Note that the differences between the expected and observed counts (i.e. the numbers in your table) are rather large. This should be a first indication that the null hypothesis of independence might be false.
- The test statistic is calculated be computing (Obs-Exp)^2/Exp for each element in the cell and summing all the elements in the table. The result is indeed 5207.162302393083 (see code below). Under the null hypothesis, this test statistic is chi2 distributed with 2 df (as you already mentioned). Compared to this distribution, the value 5207.162302393083 is truly far in the tail of the distribution making it very very unlikely to observe this outcome under the null of independence. The p-value is therefore equal to zero.

The code posted below replicates all the numbers and plots the PDF of the chi2 distribution with 2 degrees of freedom. I hope this helps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import chi2

# Data and properties
TrueCounts = np.array( [ [9170,33372],[15137,152307],[8864,56165] ])
Datadimension = TrueCounts.shape
TotalCounts = np.sum(TrueCounts)
print(TotalCounts)

# Fractions
fracAnswer = np.sum(TrueCounts, axis=0)/TotalCounts
fracRace = np.sum(TrueCounts, axis=1)/TotalCounts

# Caculate expected counts
ExpCounts = np.zeros(np.shape(TrueCounts))
for iter1 in range(Datadimension[0]):
    for iter2 in range(Datadimension[1]):
        ExpCounts[iter1, iter2] = fracRace[iter1]*fracAnswer[iter2]*TotalCounts


print('=== True and expected counts ===')
print(fracAnswer)
print(fracRace)

print('=== True and expected counts ===')
print(TrueCounts)
print(ExpCounts)

print('=== Test summary ===')
TestStat = np.sum( (TrueCounts-ExpCounts)**2/ExpCounts )
print(TestStat)

# Make ch2 plot for comparison
x = np.arange(0, 20, 0.05)
plt.plot(x, chi2.pdf(x, df=2))
plt.show()
```